# Why does changing the null hypothesis change the confidence interval?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, proportion, z-test

Using my stat calculator, I don't see why if I do two different tests with everything the same but the null hypothesis, the confidence interval is different. For example:

[image]

Has a different CI from

[image]

Why is this? In the formula, there is no mention of a null hypothesis. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's using the null value, $\pi_0$, to calculate the standard error of p, so the actual formula it's using is:
$$ p \pm 1.96 \sqrt{\pi_0 (1-\pi_0) / n}$$

Comment: I've never seen a formula that does this. Is there an intuitive explanation for why they use the null value rather than sample proportion?

Comment: @rb612 In the test of $H_0: \pi = \pi_0$, you would use $\pi_0$ in the standard error, because you're saying "well, suppose $\pi = \pi_0$." But I wouldn't do this in the confidence interval; I'd either use $p$ or 1/2.

Comment: I also thought usaully people use sample $p$ to estimate variance but not $\pi$